# ion-tabs within a modal page (@ionic/angular)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular9, ionic5

I am trying to implement a tabbed view inside a modal dialogue using ion-tabs.

As best I can tell @ionic/angular is expecting to use routing to resolve and display each tab based on the routed path .../page/tab/one, or .../page/tab/2.

I have this configured correctly for the page, however when I present the page as a modal form, the router doesn't correctly resolve the tabs (which is suppose isn't too surprising as routing isn't taking place).

Does anybody have an example of using ion-tabs inside a modal page? Thanks.

I'm using ionic-5 & angular-9.

Martin

Answer (score 0):

I found an example of what I needed in this thread.
https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/16796#issuecomment-449085001

Essential it's using CSS and boiler-plate to simulate the tab control - not ideal but works.